# BigQuery's query timing while saving to table

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using a system for exporting JSON/CSV data via saving SQL results to a named table. The problem is that today the first step of our process (executing the SQL query to a named table) is taking a huge amount of time. The same process was taking < 5 minutes the days before, while today the waiting time exceeded 30 minutes.

The job ID of such a query is *job_LW3FRWLJw6dg551pfrG6lwYvlwc*. Is it a spike? Normal queries (not saved) are being executed as expected.

Comment: The only page that I know of right now is the [bigquery-downtime-notify page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bigquery-downtime-notify). Other than that, I watch on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery) if other have a similar problem. I also watch the [BigQuery issues page](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list) where users can report bugs.